# Past and Present Perfect tenses in a sentence. Sequence of events

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I have a question concerning Past and Present Perfect tenses/the sequence of events.

"As my school project, I *have written* a 44-pages-long research paper in which I *had analysed* the risk behaviours of 110 students and *gave* the assessment of the risk of future occurrence of cardiovascular diseases by my own developed risk assessment models."

I am not sure if this is the correct way to say it. I would appreciate every piece of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *researching* your paper you *analysed* (not *had analysed*) the risk behaviours, but in the paper itself you *analyse* your research findings and *give* an assessment of the risk.

This is because in writing about the ways in which you deal with a topic in a research paper, for example in an abstract, it is usual to use present tense. "*In this paper I analyse .. , explain .. , discuss .. , show .. , give examples ..* ," etc.

The present perfect (*have written*) is correct here if the context is one in which, for example, you are sending your teacher a notification about a project you have just finished.

This gives us the suggested corrected version:

> As my school project, I have written a 44-pages-long research paper in
>   which I analyse the risk behaviours of 110 students and give the
>   assessment of the risk of future occurrence of cardiovascular diseases
>   by my own developed risk assessment models.

Comment: I see your point here, but what if the context is a bit different? I am using this sentence in my personal statement (applying to the Uni) and my goal is to basically emphasize the things I have done that relate to my chosen major. I have (or had?) written this paper a year ago and now I want to tell what I have done in it (to basically show that it is finished). I hope this makes sense... Should I use your corrected version in that case? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @lunarmint. If you are including this text in an application letter and you wrote the paper a year ago, then I would use the past simple for each verb: "_As my school project, I wrote a 44-pages-long research paper in which analysed the risk behaviours of 110 students and gave the assessment of the risk of future occurrence of cardiovascular diseases by my own developed risk assessment models._"